# Checking if a string begins with integer after line breaks

Tags: java, regex, string, line-breaks

I'm using Apache POI to read in from a .doc file, as a result, I have an arraylist of strings containing large amounts of line breaks, and tabs, from the original document formatting

I need to check if a string, from this, contains an integer as it's first character. However strings often come out like the following:

[image]

Now the first string, at location [3] is fine, even though it contains an integer later on, however the string at position [4] which starts with `\n\r\n5.2`
and therefore starts with an integer, is not acceptable and should be disregarded.
However, I cannot seem to find a way of checking if one of these strings starts with an integer. I have attempted to replace all \n and \r within the strings using java's

```
theString.replaceAll("\\\\n","");
theString.replaceAll("\\\\r","");
```

Yet this seemed to fail, I've attempted to use regex to determine using a substring if the string itself begins with an integer to no avail, as the number of tabs and line breaks varies.

Does anyone have a why by which I can determine if the string (after all line breaks and tabs) begins with an integer?

Second Example:

[image]

Code in use :

```
tempLineBreakRemoval = listoflines.get(x);
    tempLineBreakRemoval = tempLineBreakRemoval.replaceAll("\\\n", "");
   //Selection Statement to only add to "tempCommentString" if does not start with integer
    tempCommentString += listoflines.get(x);
    x++;
```

Comment: `Yet this seemed to fail`. Do you mean the `replaceAll` method did not do what it was supposed to? This may be because you need to reassign the return value of `replaceAll` to `theString` since `String` in Java is immutable. Also, why exactly do you use `\\\\n` and `\\\\r`?

Comment: Also `"\\\\n"` matches a literal backslash, followed by the letter `n` - if these are actual linebreaks, you should replace `"[\r\n]+"` with `""`.

Comment: `trim` also removes leading and trailing whitespace  eg `theString = theString.trim();`

Comment: @ChetanKinger The replaceAll did not remove the \n or \r character, the \\\ was used to resolve the special characters, isn't \ an escape character in java strings?

Comment: Yes it is but you only need \\ to make one \ and the n is a simple letter.

Comment: **to many questions in a single question**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For once the `\\\\n` is `\\n` after resolving the special characters. Therefore you have to use `\\n` if you want it to be `\n` which would be the character `\` and the letter `n`. This would be correct for replaceAll. For replace which takes a character you would even have to use `'\n'` directly. Same for `\r`and `\t`.

However i would prefer a single regex for this. This call should do it: `theString.matches("\\s*\\d.*");`. `\s` stands for any whitespace character `\d` for any digit and `.` for any other trailing character.

Comment: This would return true in the event that any digit occurred after a whitespace character, would this include a space itself?

Comment: Yes. In case you don't want this you would have to use a regex like this `"[\\n\\r\\t]*\\d.*"`

Comment: The regex was meant for the `theString.matches` method not for the replace all method ;) Call `tempLineBreakRemoval.matches("[\\n\\r\\t]*\\d.*");` If it returns true it starts with a digit if false it does not.